# PHP: Cannot assign string value to variable

Tags: php, string

```
if($page_name == "top_sites"){

$page_text = "<a href="http://www.mysite.com/top-site">Top 200</a>";
}
```

this code not work 
 please help me to correct it

Comment: Why thje mysql tag? This question has nothing to do with mysql!

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape your `"`

So just put a `\` before them:

```
$page_text = "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/top-site\">Top 200</a>";
```

Alternatively you could use single quotes round the string:

```
$page_text = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/top-site">Top 200</a>';
```

Comment: $header_title = "<a href="#">. $category .</a>";
how to fix this?

Comment: You just need to close the string before you concatenate it with another: "<a href="#">".$category."</a>"

Comment: Sorry forgot to escape the quotes in your href.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($page_name == "top_sites"){

    $page_text = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/top-site">Top 200</a>';

}
```

Comment: $header_text = " // "<a href="#">. $category .</a>" // ". $title2. " Wallpaper";

Comment: $header_text = "<a href="#">. $category .</a>";

Comment: @Hassan : please let me know what are the mistakes in my answer?

Comment: @Hassan - $header_text = "<a href=\"#\">$category</a>"; or $header_text = '<a href="#">'.$category.'</a>';  Learn how to escape quotes in strings, and you won't need to ask for help every time you need to do it

Comment: this thread appears to be heading down a cul-de-sac..