# Fixing code php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Cannot assign string value to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470460/php-cannot-assign-string-value-to-variable)

```
if($page_name == "home"){
$header_text = "<a href="http://www.mysite.com/d">. $category .</a>";
}
```

how to fix it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470460/php-cannot-assign-string-value-to-variable why?

Comment: What was the problem with previous answers so you started a new one?

Answer (score 1):

First echo out `$header_text = "<a href="http://www.mysite.com/d">. $category .</a>";`

And then try to echo out `$header_text = "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/d\"> $category </a>";`

or `$header_text = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/d">'. $category .'</a>';`.

Note in the first case, you have got error, and you will not get results.

Comment: @Hassan glad to help. Consider to accept some answers, you haven't accepted any yet.

Comment: @Hassan I meant that .. on the right corner of my answer, there's a tick icon, you must click on the post which you find most helpful. That is called acceping.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($page_name == "home"){
    $header_text = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/d">'. $category .'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($page_name == "home") {
    $header_text = "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/d\">. $category .</a>";
}
```

You need to escape your quotes.  Any time you want to have a character that also has a symbolic meaning it needs to be escaped to use its literal meaning.

Read more on escape sequences here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```
if($page_name=="home")
{
   $header_text = '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/d">'. $category .'</a>';
   // Or,  $header_text = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/d'>$category</a>";
}
```